# Can't enter password for luks disk encryption after nvidia drivers installed

Tags: grub2, nvidia, tty, luks, 15.10

I've just done a fresh install of 15.10. After installing the nvidia drivers for my quadro 600, I was able to improve the tty resolution by setting:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

in /etc/default/grub, but now when the password login screen displays, I'm unable to enter the password in the input box. I've tried ctl+alt+f1 and other things to try to enter it, but haven't found what works.

I'm able to enter it if I set nomodeset, but that puts me back at a low resolution.

Comment: Any solution to this? I'm having a similar problem after installing nvidia drivers.

Comment: No real solution. I had to drop it down into low resolution with nomodeset to be able to enter it. It's ugly, but I didn't ahve time to mess with it further.

Comment: I did something similar - edited /etc/default/grub to change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to "", then "sudo update-grub". Low res startup, but can type in unlock passwd.

Comment: Here is my solution: http://realtechtalk.com/LUKS_unable_to_type_password_to_unlock_during_boot_on_Debian_Ubuntu_and_Mint-2226-articles What I found is that after a kernel update that I couldn't type the LUKS password. In my experience it is usually caused by not having the "extra" kernel modules installed. Even if you use quietboot or Esc to enter the password, you may find your system is still broken after booting due to missing other "extra" modules that you were using.